# Use of Undeclared indentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, undeclared-identifier

An error came up with [mpc [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]][[initWithContentURL:url]]]; it says initWithContentURL is a Undeclared Indentifier. How do I fix that?

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *mpc;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *stringpath;[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Lake Weekend September 13-14" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *url = [[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringpath]
    [mpc [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]][[initWithContentURL:url]]];
    [mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
    
    [[self view ]addSubview:mpc.view];
    
    [mpc setFullscreen:YES];
    
    [mpc play];
}
@end
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon(terminator) at the end of this instruction  "NSURL *url = [[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringpath]"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared url before using it? You're trying to use it within the declaration of it...

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringpath]
[mpc [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]][[initWithContentURL:url]]];
```

You should at least have a semi colon after the first line.. then you will be able to use url. Plus you would need to sort out your additional brackets, try this..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringpath];
mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
```

Comment: NSURL *url = [[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringpath];
[mpc [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]][[initWithContentURL:url]]]; // note the semi colon..

Answer (score 0):

Your alloc/init of mpc looks all wrong. That line looks all garbled to me. I think that that line should read something like:

```
mpc=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
```